# Confused by LESS replace() function behavior

Tags: css, regex, less

I'm trying to write a LESS mixin that uses part of a string to form a class name. I expected to be able to use `replace()` to provide a value for a variable and then use the variable in the rule. Here's the test I wrote to verify that it would work:

```
.foo(@xyz) {
  @pfx: replace(@xyz, "(.).*", "$1");

  .@{pfx}-foo { margin: 0; }
}

.foo(abcdefghijklmnop);
```

When I run that through lessc (1.7.4) (*edit* - also 2.1.0), it *kind-of* works, generating this:

```
.aaa-foo {
  margin: 0;
}
```

So, the `replace()` correctly plucks the first character ("a") from the string I pass in, but instead of

```
.a-foo
```

it gives me

```
.aaa-foo
```

I've looked at the source for the `replace()` function and it's dirt-simple, so I'm just completely confused about what's going on. (I've tried the regex as `"^(.).*$"` with the same result.)

I extended the test a little:

```
.foo(@xyz) {
  @pfx: replace(@xyz, "(.).*", "$1");

  .@{pfx}-foo { margin: 0; content: "@{pfx}"; }
}

.foo(abcdefghijklmnop);
```

which gives me:

```
.aaa-foo {
  margin: 0;
  content: "a";
}
```

which means that the regex is working fine.

Comment: did `.foo(abcdefghijklmnop);` generate `.aaa-foo`?

Comment: @AmitJoki yes. If I change it to `.foo(zebra)`, it gives me `.zzz-foo`.

Comment: @AmitJoki I really want it to be `.a-foo` - it looks like LESS is internally giving the variable the right value, but when it uses the variable in that particular context (making a class name in a selector) it repeats the value like that. It's strange.

Comment: @AmitJoki ha ha yes that was one of the first things I tried!  It makes no difference, unfortunately.

Comment: I answered at [#2308](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2308).

Comment: @seven-phases-max yes thanks very much! I'm OK of course with the workarounds supplied here.

Comment: Just in case, this is fixed in the current master so most likely by the time someone else reads this the example works just fine (i.e. Less v2.1.1 or higher :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@pfx: e(replace(@xyz, "^(.).*$", "$1"));
```

Or this:

```
@pfx: replace(~"@{xyz}", "^(.).*$", "$1");
```

See documentation for the [e](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e) function.

Comment: Yes I just found this too (via random experiment). Do you know why this works, and why it's not necessary in order for `@{p}` to work properly on the right side of the `content:` property?

Comment: I assume it's something that has to do with string conversion. But I can't point out the real problem here to be honest.

Comment: Hmm. It seems to act the same way with the newest (2.1.0) version. I logged a bug to see what the maintainer says; I'm far from being an expert with the tool.

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2645-thinking-about-strings-quotes-tokens-and-tildes-in-less-css.htm may explain.

Comment: This one too: https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/functions/string.js#L17

Comment: I agree that it has something to do with the value being regarded as quoted, but the result without calling `e()` is still not what I'd expect.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently a few workarounds are provided, but how it works still a myth.

The AST after evaluation was totally correct, which looks like:

```
Element { combinator: { value: '', emptyOrWhitespace: true },
  value: '.',
  index: 54,
  currentFileInfo: 
   { filename: 'input',
     relativeUrls: undefined,
     rootpath: '',
     currentDirectory: '',
     entryPath: '',
     rootFilename: 'input' } },
Element { combinator: { value: '', emptyOrWhitespace: true },
  value: 
   Quoted { escaped: undefined,
     value: 'a',
     quote: 'a',
     index: undefined,
     currentFileInfo: undefined },
  index: 55,
  currentFileInfo: 
   { filename: 'input',
     relativeUrls: undefined,
     rootpath: '',
     currentDirectory: '',
     entryPath: '',
     rootFilename: 'input' } },
Element { combinator: { value: '', emptyOrWhitespace: true },
  value: '-foo',
  index: 61,
  currentFileInfo: 
   { filename: 'input',
     relativeUrls: undefined,
     rootpath: '',
     currentDirectory: '',
     entryPath: '',
     rootFilename: 'input' } }
```

But when generating the CSS code, the things go south quickly.

```
Quoted.prototype.genCSS = function (context, output) {
    if (!this.escaped) {
        output.add(this.quote, this.currentFileInfo, this.index);
    }
    output.add(this.value);
    if (!this.escaped) {
        output.add(this.quote);
    }
};
```

`Quoted` node will output the value with quote around it when it is not escaped.  Whereas, somehow, the quote is the first char of the value, say `'a'` in this case.

And when apply `e()` around `replace`, less will put `Anonymous` node in the AST instead of `Quoted` node, thus no quote will be outputted.

Comment: Wow. Well that is kind-of what I imagined must be happening, judging from the way that `Quoted()` constructor looks. The `replace()` function sets the quote of the return value to whatever the quote value was from the original string (or the empty string).

Comment: The AST is incorrect. The Quote object constructed by `replace` for this example is invalid.

Comment: The `replace` works fine. But then the `Quoted` node will evaluate it self in the evaluation procedure. and the quote (yet `''`) will be appended to the content, and being used to generated new `Quoted` node. check https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/tree/quoted.js#L45

Comment: @seven-phases-max this AST is dumped after evaluation, so the Quoted node is not the same as the one after `replace()`

Comment: @xiaoyi Well, nope, it's `replace` that uses `Quoted` constructor incorrectly (when input value is `Keyword`) not in opposite ;)

Comment: Technically I guess it can be fixed by explicitly setting `escaped` parameter of the constructor to `true` when input of the `replace` is of type `Keyword` (or similar). Currently it results in `undefined` hence `false` hence `Quoted` tries to use the first character as quotes...

Comment: Why 3 times `a` then?

Comment: @haim770 As it will output `quote + value + quote`, and the `quote` is set to 'a' when evaluating the AST.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.foo(@xyz) {
  @props: ~`"@{arguments}"`;

  @pfx: replace(@props, "^(.).*$", "$1");

  .@{pfx}-foo { margin: 0; }
}

.foo(abcdefghijklmnop);
```

**EDIT**

Also answering the comment, you want to pass a string to replace, actually a simpler version would be to use `.foo(~"abcdefghijklmnop")` that forces less to consider the parameter as string without outputting the quotes.

Comment: Do you understand why this makes a difference? It does work but I don't get how.

Comment: Yes, it's becoming a little clearer, though the behavior still seems undesirable. I'd rather use the `e()` approach because the actual strings I'll be passing are things like `margin` or `padding`, and quoting those with `~" "`  would look ugly. Thank you, however, for the insight; LESS is not my strongest skillset :)